# Android BLE is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently i am working on Android BLE. In this i have two questions.

1. I want to receive beacon devices as background. For example if i went to shopping mall and beacon is available in that mall then my application should receive that device without any user interaction. Is there any receiver for receiving beacon.
2. We can use IPhone as Beacon and i did a sample for BLE from below link reference

   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find

But i am receiving **UNKNOWN_DEVICE**, **UNKNOWN_SERVICE** and **UNKNOWN_CHARACTERISTIC** while advertising from IPhone. But i am getting device address with UNKNOWN_DEVICE name.

I am not able to receive data in correct format and i would like to get beacon devices without user interaction.

Could anyone reply to my question.

Thanks in advance.